# Clean (remove all from) the table on Android

Tags: android, database, sqlite

Could you please tell me how to make a fonction on Android which will delate all what i have in my table named user.

Could I do do this with the SQLiteOpenHelper class and if yes, then how?

Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

use this:

```
db.execSQL("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS TABLENAME");
```

db is an instance of SQLiteDatabse: http://developer.android.com/reference/android/database/sqlite/SQLiteDatabase.html#execSQL(java.lang.String)

Comment: Thank you, this can work too: db.execSQL("DELETE FROM user");

Comment: DROP TABLE removes the Table from the database schema and the disk file its not the alternate of "DELETING data".
The user has to CREATE the Table again after DROPING it.

Answer (score 3):

Do something like this

```
public boolean deleteAll(){

        return mDb.delete(DATABASE_TABLE, "1", null) > 0;

    }
```

Answer (score 1):

You can clear a table from your database with:

```
db.delete("user", null, null);
```

The "delete" function will clear your table.